# Reload page via jQuery changing value of a parameter

Tags: jquery, reload

I have a page with URL like:

```
www.mydomain.com/orders.html?orderNumber=363035001&return=true
```

I need a way to reload the page **via jQuery** at a specific event, **changing last parameter**. So url to be reload should be:

```
www.mydomain.com/orders.html?orderNumber=363035001&return=false
```

Comment: in which event you need to change this url ?

Comment: I have a bootstrap modal in it. On close of this modal with ( `.on('hidden.bs.modal')` ), page should be reloaded changing the parameter

Comment: `.on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){window.location = "www.mydomain.com/orders.html?orderNumber=363035001&return=false"})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this you  first get the URL form the current page, then change from true to false or viceversa, and then change the location.

```
URL = document.URL;

if(URL.indexOf('return=true') != -1)
       URL = URL.replace('return=true','return=false');
else
      URL = URL.replace('return=false','return=true'); 

window.location = URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `window.location` var to the url you want.

```
window.location = "www.mydomain.com/orders.html?orderNumber=363035001&return=false"
```

[Here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php) is a simple example

Comment: So? Make the string for the URL variable too. asign it to a variable, manipulate as you wish and call to `window.location = yourString` when you need it

Comment: So, I need to get also current URL... can you help me on this with some more detail?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href="www.mydomain.com/orders.html?orderNumber=363035001&return=false"
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally benefit from some added explanation.